# Who can I select the same index but from 2 different arrays witch change from the user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to turn two enemies into just one enemy by changing the array depending on the user input.

I've created two different enemies and two different functions for the attack, but I wanted to just create one attack to give to the diferent enemies.

```
#Warrior
warrior = [32,5,2,5,2] #HP, MP , AP, WP, Init 

#vampire 1
vampire1 = [15,0,2,2,2] #HP, MP, AP, WP, Init

#vampire 2
vampire2 = [15,0,2,2,2] #HP, MP, AP, WP, Init

#Attack from the warrior on the enemy 1
def warrior_attack1(): #If the vampire1 got the armor up
    if vampire1[2] > 0: #If the vampire1 got the armor up, then attack the armor
        vampire1[2] = vampire1[2] - random.randrange(1,warrior[3]) #Enemy's AP less the random number inside WP from the warrior
        if vampire1[2] > 0: 
            print("You damaged the enemy armor! Enemy's current armor :" + str(vampire1[2]))
        elif vampire1[2] <= 0:
            print("You have destroyed the enemy armor!")
    elif vampire1[2] <= 0: #If the vampire1 got no armor, then attack life
        vampire1[0] = vampire1[0] - random.randrange(1,warrior[3]) #Enemy's HP less the random number inside WP from the warrior
        if vampire1[0] > 0:
            print("You hit the enemy, enemy current life: " + str(vampire1[0]))
            
#Attack from the warrior on the enemy 2
def warrior_attack2(): #If the vampire2 got the armor up
    if vampire2[2] > 0: #If the vampire2 got the armor up, then attack the armor
        vampire2[2] = vampire2[2] - random.randrange(1,warrior[3]) #Enemy's AP less the random number inside WP from the warrior
        if vampire2[2] > 0: 
            print("You damaged the enemy armor! Enemy's current armor :" + str(vampire2[2]))
        elif vampire2[2] <= 0:
            print("You have destroyed the enemy armor!")
    elif vampire2[2] <= 0: #If the vampire2 got no armor, then attack life
        vampire2[0] = vampire2[0] - random.randrange(1,warrior[3]) #Enemy's HP less the random number inside WP from the warrior
        if vampire2[0] > 0:
            print("You hit the enemy, enemy current life: " + str(vampire2[0]))

def warrior_turn():
            command = input("\nWarrior is playing: " +
                            "\nChoose your action" + 
                            "\n1. Attack." +
                            "\n2. Magic.\n")
            if command == "1": #Execute the warrior attack
                command = input("\nEach enemy do you want to attack?: " +
                                "\n1. Vampire 1" + 
                                "\n2. Vampire 2" +
                                "\n3. Vampire 3" +
                                "\n4. Vampire 4\n") #Let the player select what enemy he want's to attack
                if command == "1":
                    if vampire1[0] > 0: #If the vampire 1 is alive
                        warrior_attack1() #Attack enemy 1
                    else: #If the vampire 1 is dead
                        print("The vampire 1 is dead, choose another target!")
                        warrior_turn()

warrior_turn()
```

Comment: You could use a list of list for storing the enemies and you can pass the index of the enemy you want to attack `warrior_attack()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of enemy:

```
vampires = [[15,0,2,2,2], [15,0,2,2,2]]
```

I've modified a bit the attack function
(`vampire := vampire - damage` for assignment within condition check)
(no need to check twice in elif, a simple else does the trick)
(don't put comments within code, ahead the function it's clearer)

```
def warrior_attack(index):
    damage = random.randrange(1, warrior[3])
    if vampires[index][2] > 0:
        if (vampires[index][2]:= vampires[index][2] - damage) > 0: 
            print("You damaged the enemy armor! Enemy's current armor :" + str(vampires[index][2]))
        else:
            print("You have destroyed the enemy armor!")
    else:
        if (vampires[index][0] := vampires[index][0] - damage) > 0:
            print("You hit the enemy, enemy current life: " + str(vampires[index][0]))
        else:
            print("You killed the enemy !")
```

And in warrior_turn function, in enemy selection part:

```
            if command.isdigit():
                index = int(command)
                if index >= len(vampires):
                    print("The vampire {} doesn't exist, there is only {] enemies".format(index, len(vampires)))
                    warrior_turn()
                if vampires[index][0] > 0:
                    warrior_attack(index)
                else:
                    print("The vampire {} is dead, choose another target!".format(index))
                    warrior_turn()
            else:
                print("Bad entry, please write down a number")
```

Keep in mind that you call the function warrior_turn within warrior_turn, better to do a loop than resistivity (might crash the game with stack error).